# How to generate different pages from a click in ng-repeat list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, materialize

I have this code, and this is what it does:
It generates a list of topics from a json.
These topics will be used to determinate a page in the "CONTENT" area.

But, how can i make a "link" or "way" to call/create every page for every item in that list.

**Exists a way to verify what item has been clicked? and call the respective page from that item ?**

```js
angular.module('duall')
.controller('documentationController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

 $scope.docs = [];

 $http.get('static/titles.json').success(function(doc){
  $scope.docs = doc;
 }).error(function(error){
  console.log(error);
 });

}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="documentationController">
<div class="row">
  
  
  <div  class="col s3" >
    
    <!-- Search Box -->
    <div class="input-field col s12" >      
      <input id="search" type="search" ng-model="q" aria-label="filter docs"/>
             <label for="search">
              <strong>
                Pesquise Algo! :)
              </strong>
             </label>
      <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Search Box -->
    
    <ul class="animate-container">       
      <li  ng-repeat="docs in docs | filter:q as results">
        <a class="" href="{{docs.title}}">
          {{docs.title}}
        </a>
      </li>
      
      <!-- if no results -->
      <li ng-if="results.length === 0">
        <strong>Nada encontrado :(</strong>
      </li>
    </ul>      
        
  </div> <!-- end col s3 -->
  
  <div class="col s9">
      <h1>CONTENT</h1>
  </div><!-- end col s9 -->


</div><!-- end ROW -->
</div><!-- end Controller -->
```

Comment: why dont you store `link` along with `text` in your `doc` variable.?

Comment: Take a look at ng-click. That will trap your click in an angular way and then you handle that in your controller. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick